# Can boot with external SSD via USB, but can't boot USB flash drive with same data

Tags: usb, startup, ssd

I have a SSD, which I'm using to boot sometimes from. Yosemite is installed on it. I have some legacy apps there which do not run on newer OS versions (Catalina and newer).

Now I've cloned the SSD with Carbon Copy Cloner to a USB flash drive. I've used same partition scheme: GUID and partition type: Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I've checked the details with the disk utility app. Everything same, except that the icon is **orange** for the SSD and **grey** for the USB flash drive and the ownership state is enabled for the SSD, but disabled for the USB flash drive. But I've changed that and tried to boot afterwards. Still without success.

I can boot the SSD from a MacbookPro 2014 and Macbook Air 2013 without any issues.
But I can't boot the USB flash drive.
At the beginning it looks fine, I can choose the disk to boot, then some text appear but for the USB flash I see at the end a forbidden icon. On the MacbookPro, I have some debug output during boot (via OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher) and I see a big difference but I don't understand the reason.

[image]
This is the USB flash drive, this is the text before the forbidden icon is shown

[image]
This is the SSD drive, connected via USB.